# Troubleshooting database-backed custom session handler - values are not persisting between page loads

Tags: php, session

I am trying to get my custom sessions working but my variables do not persist from page to page. If I remove the require line and replace it with session_start(); it works fine. All of these files are in the same directory and I have session.save_handler set to user in my php.ini file.

**first HTML page**

```
<?php 
require("sessionSetup.php");

$_SESSION['test'] = "session test";
session_regenerate_id();

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>sessions test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
alert("Test: <?php echo $_SESSION['test'];?>");

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="session2.php">Click here to go to session2.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**second HTML page**

```
<?php
require("sessionSetup.php");
//session_start();  

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>sessions test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
alert("Test: <?php echo $_SESSION['test'];?>");

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="session.php">Click here to go to session.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**sessionSetup.PHP**

```
<?php
session_set_save_handler('_open','_close','_read','_write','_destroy','_clean');
session_start();


function _open(){
global $_sess_db;
if($_sess_db = mysql_connect(host,user,password)){
    return mysql_select_db(db, $_sess_db)or die("cannot select DB");
}
return false;   
} 
function _close(){
global $_sess_db;
return mysql_close($_sess_db);
}
function _read($id){
global $_sess_db; 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id); 
$sql = "SELECT data FROM session WHERE id = '$id'";
if ($result = mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
        return $record['data'];
    }
} 
return '';
}
function _write($id, $data){
global $_sess_db; 
$access = time(); 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$access = mysql_real_escape_string($access);
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data); 
$sql = "REPLACE INTO session VALUES ('$id', '$access', '$data')"; 
return mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db);
}
function _destroy($id){
global $_sess_db; 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id); 
$sql = "DELETE FROM session WHERE id = '$id'"; 
return mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db);
}
function _clean($max){
global $_sess_db; 
$old = time() - $max;
$old = mysql_real_escape_string($old); 
$sql = "DELETE FROM session WHERE access < '$old'"; 
return mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db);
}

?>
```

I have replace the database login stuff with dummy information here. Also when I check with phpadmin there is no info in my sessions db. All I get on the second HTML page is a null value. I have been working on this for a while now and have made no progress. Any help I could get wiould be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Debugging is every developer everyday work. So just do it.

Comment: I have not used custon sessions before and think that the problem is something I am not understanding as opposed to something wrong in the code.

Comment: @user052211: your question says other things. Write small **working** custom sessions handler example, without html, all-in-one-file, without database (based on files, as it is more simple) and upgrade it to use DB step-by-step after. And just after that move it to your code.

Comment: the PHP sessions file is one I got from an online tutoral. this was my starting point. I have been trying to get it to work for the last 3 days. This is not my job I am makeing a webpage for my wife's bussiness.

Comment: @user052211: so revert back to the **working** code and change it to use DB by **small** steps.

Comment: Using code you don't understand is a major time-killer. Start with simple session mecanism as zerkms advised, if you really need DB based sessions (which I doubt) it can be added after.

Comment: I got it working. It was a database issue

Comment: @user052211 Glad to hear you got it sorted out.  Would you mind posting your solution as an answer so that other developers can reference it if they run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok.

Make sure your database table used for storing session data is correctly set up, because session handler functions don't seem to have any error checking.

The most probable cause of your sessions not working is either id or data column of session table not big enough to hold full info. Access should be int, try different sizes of varchar for id and data.

Comment: It turns out that I had an extra field in my database and my code was ignoring it. Once I added a ," " to my replace statement it worked fine. I ended up deleteing the unneeded field and removeing the ," ". I wrote a small php file that just tried to insert something into the database, and one I realized that it was not working it was easy to figure out from there.

Answer (score 0):

As emphasized in the php manual page on [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) it ***MUST*** go before anything is outputted to the browser. Most likely your required file (`sessionSetup.php`) has a couple empty bits at the beginning or end which are not being interpreted as php and therefore being outputted to the bowser. To fix this simply put `session_start` before `require("sessionSetup.php");` (also don't forget to remove session_start from your session setup file once you do that). OR you could create an [output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).